# Why is this enumeration of this IQueryable causing the database connection to time out?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following `IQueryable<T>`:

```
IQueryable<DAL.Products> _results;
```

Within a search and filter algorithm, I use `LINQ` to call up a SQL function that conducts a `Freetext` search based on a key word or phrase:

```
  //Key phrase
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Keyword1))
  {
      _results = Entities.KeyphraseSearch(filter.Keyword1);
  }
```

No problems there, it is fast even when searching several hundred thousand records.

Downstream of that, I have as one of my filtering criteria a check for certain tags:

```
//Tags
  if (filter.Tags.Any())
  {
        var taggedProducts = _results.Where(w => w.TaggedProducts.Any(a => 
                           filter.Tags.Contains(a.Tags.Id))).Select(s => s.Id);
         _results = _results.Where(w => taggedProducts.Contains(w.Id));
  }
```

This is also no problem **IF** it is not used in conjunction with the key word search (more on that below).  Used without key word searching, it shreds through the database and returns only the relevant results in seconds.

## The Problem

Obviously, at some point you have to enumerate the `IQueryable` and return the results to the user, typically by using `.Skip()` and `.Take()` for paging.  I also return a total result count:

```
var resultCount = _results.Count();
```

Here is the thing, when I use the key word search in conjunction with the tags, anytime I hit an enumeration (like `.Count()`), the code stalls and ultimately the database connection times out.

I have myriad other filtering criteria, like dates, product types, etc and everything else works very well in conjunction with the key word search, just not this tagging operation.

I can't see any obvious reason why the enumeration would cause a time out when both tagging and keyword searching occurs.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you catch the query in SQL Profiler and run it in Management Studio? Does it complete then?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild statistics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's passing the `taggedProducts` code into the `_result` code as a subquery.  I'll guess that if you add `.ToArray()` at the end, it'll go as two fast queries instead of one slow query.

```
   var taggedProducts = _results.Where(w => w.TaggedProducts.Any(a => 
                  filter.Tags.Contains(a.Tags.Id))).Select(s => s.Id).ToArray();

     _results = _results.Where(w => taggedProducts.Contains(w.Id));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this approach but it didn't solve the problem.  However, you did put me on a new train of thought that might lead me to the solution. . .stay tuned.

Comment: Bingo!  Two things needed to happen: First, I needed to make a dedicated query directly to my table that holds product-tag pairs RATHER than relying on Entity Framework's built-in relationship.  Second, I needed to call `.ToArray()` thereby creating a distinct constraint against which to check my super set of results.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!